# div's p descendend strange formatted when p is styled before

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

I want to skill up my css skill up, so I doing some excercises. One of them is create 80% width div with paragraph inside of it. 
So I created div:

```
<div class="centered">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, at?</p>
</div>
```

than I created styles for it:

```
 .centered {
            width: 80%;
            height: 100vh;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: indianred;
            /*border: 1px solid black; */
            margin: auto;
 }
```

and then I discovered than `p` paragraph is outside the div element. Like on the screen: 
[image]

I investigeted a little bit and find out I have some `p` styling before div styling:

```
p {
        color: gray;
        background: white;
        font-style: normal;
  }
```

And that was the problem, so I created `.centered>p` stiling with higher specificity, like so:

```
.centered>p {
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: inherit;
}
```

and that helps. But I also discovered one thing: When I add border to div element, the `p` paragraph jumps into this div(just comment out border property from div styling block). Result looks like so:
[image]

Could you please explain what is the connection between this `div` and `p` elements? Why `p` is not a part of a div when it is styled before? And why it IS part of a div when div get some border?

I don't get it. It is a css-specificity issue? I put all code to this question as a snipped, but it also can be found on codepen -> 
https://codepen.io/nowakpawel/pen/jOPvmMv

```css
p {
        color: gray;
        background: white;
        font-style: normal;
    }
.centered {
        width: 80%;
        height: 100vh;
        text-align: center;
        /* line-height: 100vh; */
        background-color: indianred;
/*         border: 1px solid black; */
        margin: auto;
    }
/* .centered>p {
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: inherit;
    } */
```

```html
<div class="centered">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing         elit. Animi, at?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: *Why p is not a part of a div when it is styled before?* --> it's a part of the div but the background is white so it seems outside (remove the background and you will notice this) ... for the other part it's about margin collapsing (note that p has a default margin

Comment: Thank You TemaniAfif I fell so noobie now :D I don't know why I didn't notice that before.